# How to extract attributes from a vector layer within areas bound by polygons that are defined in another vector layer, in QGIS 3.1?

Tags: qgis-3, fields-attributes, qgsvectorlayer

I have a few polygons defined in a vector layer (Layer A). I have another vector layer (Layer B) that contains two attributes (slope and elevation).

How can I extract the slope and elevation values in B that are bound by areas in A?

[image]

Comment: can you please add a graphical illustration of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a standard spatial join. Depending on how you want to extract the values from Layer B, use the "Join attribute by location"  or   "Join attribute by location (summary)" algorithm from the Processing Toolbox.

https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_spatial_joins.html

Comment: Yes, that is how I ended up doing it. It's a two step process, I was hoping there might be a simpler single step process to do the same. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why you need 2 steps? You should be able to extract both attributes in a single step.

Comment: Earlier I was extracting the attributes by location and then doing a spatial join. I tried out just doing the spatial join, as you suggested. It becomes a problem because I am working with a million slope and elevation values and QGIS slows down each time I open up the attribute table. I discovered that it is better to do it in a two step process (extract the attributes that I am interested in and then perform a spatial join). Thanks for your comments and suggestions.

Comment: A tip to speed up your join is to use a spatial index. Build the index on the layers which would take only a few seconds but would significantly speed up the join. Also the join algorithm allows you to choose which of the output fields you want to keep (which is the same as doing extract attributes step) https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/advanced-qgis.html#spatial-indexing